# Как исправить функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Доброго времени суток!
Есть функция

---

```
def conv(self):
    self.iniString = []
    for self.files in os.listdir(self.dir):
        # Фильтр на .ini файлы.
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(self.files, '*.ini'): 
            with open(self.dir + '/' + self.files) as file:
                # Считываем .ini файл в список
                self.iniString = file.read().splitlines()
                # Забираем имя файла
                self.fileName = os.path.splitext(self.files)[0] 
                # Создаем в заданной директории файл с именем self.fileName.json
                self.jsonFiles = open(self.dir + '/' + self.fileName + '.json', 'w') 
                self.jsonFile = ' \n'.join(self.iniString)
                self.jsonFiles.write(self.jsonFile)
```

---

Такая проблемка `self.iniString` присваивается 2 списка, т. к. в выбранной директории хранится 2 - .ini файла, затем в заданной директории создается 2 - .json файла, как собственно и положено, но содержимое 2 - х списков из `self.iniString` записывается в первый .json. Как поправить таким образом, что 1 - й список в 1 .json, а 2 - й во второй?

Comment: Приведённый вами код и так записывает данные в соответствующие файлы. Проблема не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 1):

После записи данных в файл .json

```
self.jsonFiles.write(self.jsonFile)
```

закройте файл функцией close().

```
self.jsonFiles.close()
```